# Xcode 8 Stuck at Indexing and uses up all free space in the storage

Tags: xcode, indexing, xcode8, unreal-engine4

I am a Unreal C++ Developer and I'm using Xcode as my primary editor for my Unreal projects. Everything was fine with Xcode 7.3.1. Yesterday, I upgraded Xcode from 7.3.1 to 8.0. While opening Unreal Projects in Xcode 8, Xcode freezes at Indexing and also free space on Macintosh SSD is used up drastically by Xcode or whatever(I don't know since the SSD space is completely used up hence I can't even close any running applications. It just freezes). I tried,

- Deleting everything in "Derived Cache/" folder and rebooting Mac
- Re generating Xcode project from Unreal Editor
- Emptying out build folder and started rebuilding from scratch.
- Re installing Xcode 8

> Please note that it is not the problem of low space or out of memory.

Because I've more than 100 GB free and 8 GB RAM. But the problem is the free space is used up so fast like several GB's per second! I can't even imagine Xcode or my SSD will have write speed like that. And it is specifically for Unreal Projects alone.

But nothing seems to work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any luck sorting this out? I am going to try downgrading Xcode to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation version 4.13.0 and 4.13.1 of Unreal triggers that index bug in Xcode 8.

I uninstalled Xcode (drag to Trash from Applications) then downgraded to [Xcode 7.3.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3.1/Xcode_7.3.1.dmg) via downloading from the ["more" section of the Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Then re-setup and regenerated the Engine source with Xcode 7.3.1 installed.  Then I regenerated my C++ project files again too.

After that I could open up project in XCode. It still took a while to index, but the memory never spiked more than 1.3 gig while I was watching it.  Left it going over night and it had finished in the morning without filling up my HD.

From what I heard there is a fix in XCode 8.1 - but at the time of writing this answer that had not yet been released.

Comment: I'm already using Xcode 7.3.1. Whenever I install new version of Xcode I'll not delete the previous one till I find the new version is comfortable for development. Anyway thank you again for your time and answer.

Comment: There's possibly another solution (until 8.1 anyway)

If you select UE4 as the project then select the settings tab, you will see three different projects on the left side of the settings window under the target. One of them is the indexing project (usually the bottom of the three). If you delete that project, then it will no longer try to index for that target.  (via Peter Sauerbrei)

Comment: Frustratingly, unless you subscribe to become an Apple Developer you can't get older versions of Xcode.  I really don't want to pay $99 just to be able to downgrade to 7.3.1

Comment: Actually - scrub that - you just need to sign in to the developer section with an existing ID.  I tried removing the indexing and it was a nightmare as you lose all autocomplete and syntax highlighting.  I've deleted xcode 8 and reverted to xcode 7.3.1 and it seems to have indexed my unreal engine code correctly now.

Comment: I got some more info from Epic. The 8.1 beta works if you need to build iOS 10 stuff right now.  They did not think reverting to 7.3.1 would impact anything else for Unreal.  Personally I'm going to stick with 7.3.1 until 8.1 is properly released.